# How can i fetch the element inside 2 {{}} in c #

Tags: c#, json.net, restsharp

```
var options = new RestClientOptions(Endpoint)
var client = new RestClient(options);
vsr request = new RestRequest();
var response = await client.GetAsync(request);
var requestContent = response.Content;
var parsed = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(responseContent);
```

the value in `parsed` is :

```
{{
"value1" : "input1",
"value2" : null,
"value3" : {"valuex" : 4,
"valuey" : 5,
"valuez" : 6}
"value4" : 17
}}
```

the value in `requestContent` :

```
"{
\"value1\" : \"input1\",
\"value2\" : null,
\"value3\" : {\"valuex\" : 4,
\"valuey\" : 5,
\"valuez\" : 6}
\"value4\" : 17
}"
```

I'm new to c#, all I want is to parse the data inside `valuez` which is `6` in this case, I tried so many things on request content like trying like deserializing and trying to parse the `parsed` value where I debugged and tried to access its child by putting `.` after parsed similar to what we'd do in javascript for example but nothing seems to be working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to DeserializeObject to an object of your type . example:

```
var parsed = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<object>(responseContent);
```

or

```
public class MyClass
{
    public string value1 { get; set; }
    public string value2 { get; set; }
}
var parsed = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyClass>(responseContent);
```

Comment: Did not work the <Object> (type or namespace could not be found)

Comment: typo "object " instead of "Object" . But the i meant by that is to Deserialize to your model type @sara

Answer (score 0):

You provided invalid JSON:

```json
{
    "value1": "input1",
    "value2": null,
    "value3": {
        "valuex": 4,
        "valuey": 5,
        "valuez": 6
    }         // <---- missing comma here.
    "value4": 17
}
```

If unsure, you can always confirm if it's valid using a tool like [JSONLint](https://jsonlint.com/) (remember to remove escape characters, which can be done using regex (online tool like [regex101](https://regex101.com/)))

given you have a valid json (so just add the comma):

```cs
var r = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string,dynamic>>(yourInputString);
```

... or as others mentioned, you can create a custom model. The easy way to do that is using another tool, i.e. [Json2csharp](https://json2csharp.com/). You can also refer to [this article](https://fullduck.dev/how-to-turn-an-api-response-into-a-csharp-class/)